# if we randomly select a number from an interval, how can we determine the parameter, and the probability that the selected number is greater than

Tags: probability

Select a random number from the interval $[2,6]$, according to the function $p_X$ (PDF)
$$p_X(x)=c(x-2)\cdot 1_{[2,6]}$$

$a)$ Find value of the parameter $c$

$b)$ Determine the probability that the selected number is greater than $4$

My attemp is: I don't know if I can mark the example given in this way
$$p_X(x)=\begin{cases} 
    c(x-2), & 2 \leq x\leq 6   \\
    0, & x\notin[2,6] \\
\end{cases}
\tag{1} $$

**Part a)**
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(x)dx=\int_2^6c(x-2)dx=1\Rightarrow\int_0^4ctdt=1\Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{8}$$

If the function could be denoted as in $(1)$ then we have:
$$
p_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{8}(x-2), & 2 \leq x\leq 6   \\
    0, & x\notin[2,6] \\
\end{cases}
$$

Case 1: If $x<2$ we have $F_X(x)=0$

Case 2: If $2\leq x\leq 6$ we have: $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{8}(t-2)dt\Rightarrow F_X(x)=\frac{1}{16}(x-2)^2$

Case 3: If $x>6$ we have $F_X(x)=1$

Now for the second part

**Part b)**

$$P(X>4)=1-P(x\leq 4)=\cdots $$

I don't know if it's okay and how to proceed

please help me understand if i solved the example well, or is it all wrong, if it is wrong, tell me how you can do it to solve it correctly. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: can someone help me please

Comment: You have a problem because if $x>2$ your pdf is negative which is impossible.

Comment: Hint for b) $P(X\leq z)$ is equal to $F_X(z)$ and that is $\int _{-\infty}^z p_X(x)dx$

Comment: can you tell me in more detail how, if you have the desire then please choose the task to see where the mistake is

Comment: it seems to me that I was clear, the example is given as shown above, everything else is my choice, I do not know if this is the right solution, or it should be solved differently

Comment: There were a few typos, I made a correction.

Comment: please, will you help me work it out correctly

Comment: Everything is fine! For b) I gave you a hint! You could work this out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106702/discussion-between-madrit-zhaku-and-fakemistake).

Comment: for part b) $$P(x\leq 4)=\int_{-\infty}^4\frac{1}{8}(x-2)dx$$ or no

Comment: That is correct! But you could also evauluate $F_X(4)$ which is easier.

Comment: how to do it, tell me by making you the solution, only for part b) since part a) is correct, i.e. $F_X(4)=\frac{1}{8}(4-2)=0.25$

Comment: $P(X>4)=1-P(X\leq 4)=1-F_X(4)=1-0.25=0.75$

Comment: For $2\leq x\leq 6$ you have $F_X(x)=\frac{1}{16}(x-2)^2$, so $F_X(4)=\frac{1}{16}(4-2)^2$

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^4\frac{1}{8}(x-2)=\lim_{a\to -\infty}\int_a^4 \frac{1}{8}(x-2)=\frac{1}{8} \lim_{a\to -\infty} \frac{(x-2)^2}{2}|_a^4=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16}\lim_{a\to -\infty}(a-2)^2$$

I think $\lim_{a\to -\infty}(a-2)^2$ is not 0

Comment: Look what you wrote in case 1)

Comment: now I have it clear, thank you